# Make 2 Different Tables Share a Common Table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to have two tables one for `Employees` and one for `Companies`, both Employees & Companies should be registered within the site, thus they should have records in the `users` table provided with Laravel. How should I structure the relationships between the models, should I go for polymorphic relationships or use one to one?

Comment: As you would do any model but just define the relationship within them.

Comment: @Script47 Sorry for being not specific, I'm going to update my post : )

Comment: I presume the user can only have a 1:1 login? So it shouldn't need to be anything else.

Comment: Yes, the tables contain profile information about the entity. The fields in the tables differ greatly, they can't be put into a single table.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add two columns to the "users" table: `userable_id` and `userable_type`. `userable_id` will be used to store the `id` of the row for the entity (`Employee` or `Company`), and the `userable_type` will hold the `class` path for the Eloquent model.

in `create_users_table` migration file add these two lines:

```php
// ...
$table->integer('userable_id')->unsigned();
$table->string('userable_type');
// ...
```

in `User.php` model:

```php
class User extends Model {
    // Add this declaration.
    public function userable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

in your `Company.php` model:

```php
class Company extends Model
{
    // Add this method.
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(User::class, 'userable');
    }
}
```

in the `Employee.php` model do the same as above:

```php
class Employee extends Model
{
    // Add this method.
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(User::class, 'userable');
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to access the `user` by running:

```php
App\Company::all()->get(1)->user;
// or
App\Employee::all()->get(1)->user;
```

And access the entity with this one-liner:

```php
App\User::all()->get(1)->userable;
```